# Flutter TextFormField inpy border color not chaning

Tags: flutter

I am trying to change the color of input border but its not changing. Only the color change when its on focus but normally its not changing the color

Code

```
                    Container(
                      height: Height * 0.08,
                      width: Width * 0.9,
                      child: TextFormField(
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 15,
                            color: Color(0xff04385f),
                            fontFamily: 'UbuntuRegular'),
                        decoration: new InputDecoration(
                          border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                color: Colors.red, width: 1.25),
                            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                              const Radius.circular(10.0),
                            ),
                          ),
                          filled: true,
                          hintStyle: new TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.grey[800],
                              fontFamily: 'UbuntuRegular'),
                          hintText: "Username",
                          fillColor: Colors.white70,
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                color: Color(0xff04385f), width: 1.25),
                            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                              const Radius.circular(10.0),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

As you can see i define red color on inputborder but its showing some dark grey color

Comment: got that fixed?

Comment: yup by enabledBorder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add enabledColor:

```
   enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: const BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.red, width: 1.25),
                        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                          const Radius.circular(10.0),
                        ),
                      ),
```